# Is this question too ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/liang-barsky-line-clipping-algorithm asks for an extension to n dimensions, but does not specify how the extension will be made, leaving the potential for ambiguity as Nathan Reed points out in a comment.

Is it clear to answerers that only one of the potential interpretations makes sense, or should this question be put on hold until it can be edited to have a specific meaning?

Or is it acceptable to have a question asking for arbitrary generalizations, so that different answers extend it to algorithms with different purposes? Maybe one that clips lines in n dimensions, another that clips n-1 dimensional hyperplanes, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

As it stands, I believe the question is too vague to be answered. We shouldn't write answers based on wild guesses at what's meant, but rather try to get clarification from the asker and have them edit it into a more specific question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have enough reputation to cast a close vote as "unclear what you're asking". ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner OK, yeah. I was just going to give them a day or two's grace to edit before I VTC. :) (And yes, I know I can retract a VTC later.)